# How to implement Setup and Deployment project with Custom Actions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-deployment

My Setup and Deployment project will copy both **MyClient.exe**, **MyClient.Config** files to the appropriate directories using the Setup.msi file.

I am trying to enhance the Setup.msi project so that user can enter  the configuration values at run time and the setup program can update the file  MyClient.Config.  I have created a new project and added a windows Form in it with edit boxes. The project will create an application named **Helper.exe**

I followed the below link and implemented the Custom Actions functionality.

[link](http://www.nullskull.com/a/783/build-a-custom-action-installhelper-configuration-editor.aspx/)

But the issue is Setup.msi is always starting the MyClient.exe instead of Helper.exe during the deployment.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest either using a different tool (this project type is removed from VS2012 and exposes very little of Windows Installer)  or move the requirement from the installer to the application (first run configuration).